# tar nests on a restoration

Tags: linux, tar, nested

Is the following a known and long-standing inconsistency/feature of tar?  I suspect the answer is yes.

```
cd mydir
tar cvpf dec14.tar .
tar xvpf dec14.tar -C .
```

Files are extracted to where they are supposed to be.

```
cd ..
tar cvpf dec14.tar mydir
tar xvpf dec14.tar -C mydir
```

Files are restored nested in mydir/mydir, in other words, nested one level lower than before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an inconsistency or bug. 'tar' is doing exactly what you told it to do. The '-C' option just means to change into the given directory first, it doesn't imply anything about trimming that string off the extracted paths.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right of course, -C is described in the man page to be a programmatic change to the given directory.  However, after executing the extraction, we end up no where different so I suppose a more complete man page would say that there is a directory change and a change back.  Perhaps, it would be a better design if the option were to be used to indicate the target path for extraction, rather than the target for a change directory operation.  After all, we don't expect to change directory if we do something like "rm mydir/*".